# How to pass data from one view to another view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, redirect, view, angular-ui-router

I am passing data on a button click from view1, now I want this data to be passed to another view (view2). I am invoking another state on button click. Please show some light how I can pass data ?

```
$scope.getSample=function(){
                $scope.spreadsheet=$scope.SpreadsheetLists.name;
                $scope.worksheet=$scope.SheetList.properties.title;
                $state.go('view2');
            };
```

**I do not want to use state parameters** like this :

```
  $state.go('view2',key:$scope.worksheet);
```

Comment: please change your tag to AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $rootScope.data = "some data"; and retrieve in other controller. or create factory methods and pass values through factory.

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the code to pass data along with URL using $state**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('view2', {
  url: "/view2",
  templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  params: { name: null }
})

$state.go("view2", {                
    name: "Dummy Name"
});
```

**Way to read the data**

```
.controller('view2Ctrl', function ($stateParams, $scope) {       
    console.log($stateParams.name);
});
```

**No other way available.**